# Get number of homescreens without calling onoffsetschanged (for wallpaper)?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm doing a live wallpaper. However, what is initially shown depends on the number of home screens. 
While onOffsetsChanged() allows you to calculate the number of home screens, it gets called only if the user scrolls the homescreen.

So is there a way to get the current xStep and xOffSet without calling onOffSetsChanged()?

Edit: I may not need to know that per se. Here's what I'm doing: I'm basically drawing a portion of the bitmap. The portion shown depends on the current homescreen.

Edit 2: so to explain what I'm trying to do---I'm basically trying to mimick the scrolling wallpaper effect but with a video. The point is that the portion shown depends on the current homescreen. Here's the problem: So the user selects the wallpaper. OnSurfaceCreated() is called, followed by onSurfaceChanged(). However, onOffSetsChanged() is never called until the user tries to scroll the homescreens. That's the problem. You don't know what part of the bitmap/video to display until the user scrolls the screen. (So Josh's suggestion doesn't work. The part of the video that's displayed may be wrong---until the user scrolls the screen and we get the correct onOffSetsChanged() values.)

Answer (score 0):

Your edit doesn't really explain why you need to know how many screens there are.  You can draw the center portion of your bitmap initially, then when xOffset changes to something like 0, draw the leftmost portion of your bitmap.  What's the issue?

Comment: see above. Hopefully, it's clearer what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm encountering

Comment: [edit 2] Hmmm, when first running a live wallpaper, I get several calls to `onOffsetsChanged` with the correct `xOffset`.  These all come after `onSurfaceChanged`, without any scrolling on my part.  Are you saying you don't get that call, or that you can't make use of that call?  Also, what launcher are you using (since your launcher is responsible for that call).